# Dojo Styling Combobox's options tags?

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

How can I set style to some options tags of `ComboBox` widget.

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox();
```

how to get options tags and set some of them style, for example I would like
to set some items (options) with `RED` text and some items (options) `GREEN.`

Please any hint any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible out of the box using `labelFunc` and `labelType`:

```
var store = new Memory({ data: [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo', color: '#900' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar', color: '#090' }
] });
var cb = new ComboBox({
    store: store,
    labelType: 'html',
    labelFunc: function (item) {
        return '<span style="color: ' + item.color + '">' + item.name + '</span>';
    }
}).placeAt(document.body);
cb.startup();
```